# Is there a way to collapse code in Visual Studio conditionally if it contains specified text?

Tags: visual-studio

I have some code that frequently contains 10 lines or so for error reporting which is repetitive and obstructs the readability of the rest of the code. The first line is an if statement that contains a phrase that could be used to find and collapse all sections handling the error reporting so that I can see all the 'normal' code that is not handling error reporting.

I can manually collapse the if statement, but does anyone know of an extension or some method of collapsing all sections of code that contains specified text?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using **regions**; and hence you can standardize your region (since it is repeated) and regions are collapsible automatically using the shortcut keys of **(Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O)**, however this will collapse your entire code.

I have the same for all my Try Catch Blocks, as the sample below:

```
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            #region Standard Exception
            catch (Exception LogError)
            {
                MyStandardClass.LogError(LogError);
            } 
            #endregion
```

When collapsed, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot when collapsed]

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that collapses all other regions too.

Comment: @guymid Yes it will, unfortunately I don't think VS has this feature for conditional collapsing of code. So I use standard regions for quick search and find. Good luck!